# How to combine text and a formula into different lines of a shape?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a shape and I want it to display the text "Current Budget" and then on a line below it the budget from a cell on the worksheet, say A1. Is this possible?

Comment: I'd honestly just use another textbox for the budget info, and yes you can [tie the shape to the cell](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dynamically-display-the-contents-of-a-cell-or-range-in-a-graphic-object-e2e7a629-5662-42d6-9295-06d112c2099f).

Answer (score 0):

First pick another cell, say **A2,** and enter:

```
="Current Budget" & CHAR(10) & A1
```

and format **A2**  with wrap.  Then run:

```
Sub dural()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 285.75, 51, 223.5, _
        179.25).Select
    Selection.Formula = "=A2"
End Sub
```

[image]

*(if you don't want to use macros, this can be done manually)*